# Best Way To Access User Permissions From View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, menu, permissions, roles

In my ASP.NET MVC site, my set up allows users to have roles, and roles have permissions.  Generally, these permissions are set for a controller.  In my site's main navigational menu,  an Authenticated user can see all items, even if they aren't authorized to access that page.

Currently I can only configure the menu based off if the user is authenticated:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated){ }
```

I'm wondering, what's the best way to pass the user's permissions to a view, only for the sake of configuring the menu for that user?  Is there some common way of doing it, or will I have to implement this myself?  I haven't found much information on it, but maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT**

Sorry I may not have been clear enough.  This is my main nav menu, in the _Layout page.  Also, permissions assigned to a role are very configurable by an admin (they can also create and delete roles), so checking if the user is in a role won't meet my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an action in say, the `CommonController`, which returns a partial view containing your navigation. This partial view can have its own model which can be populated from the controller. This allows you to use dependency injection for instance.

The action could look like this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Navigation()
{
    var model = new NavigationModel();
    // populate the model..

    return PartialView("_Navigation", model);
}
```

You can render this partial in your view (`_Layout.cshtml` in your case) like this:

```
@Html.Action("Navigation", "Common")
```

For most cases, `Request.IsAuthenticated` is just fine. Only use this if you need something more advanced.

Comment: Great idea! Just implemented it, and it works perfectly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Roles` class static method `IsUserInRole`:

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to have a property on the viewmodel that the view uses.

Comment: well my navigation menu is in my layout - all views use it

Comment: then i would say that Request.IsAuthenticated is fine